# How to get data from block.io webhook?

Tags: php, json, api, bitcoin

I'm using block.io api in my localhost. I've tested basic wallet api which contains generating new address, getting balance of an address, withdraw and etc. All of them works fine but I've stuck at Real-Time Notifications API. I can't get it done. I've set the call back url and I'm using testnet bitcoin network for testing. When a transaction occurs how can I get the data from POSTed notification to my callback.php page?? API sends me JSON data type like this

```
{
"notification_id": "..."
"delivery_attempt": 1,
"created_at": 1426104819,
"type": "address",
"data": {
  "network": "BTC",
  "address": "3cBraN1Q...",
  "balance_change": "0.01000000", // net balance change, can be negative
  "amount_sent": "0.00000000",
  "amount_received": "0.01000000",
  "txid": "7af5cf9f2...", // the transaction's identifier (hash)
  "confirmations": X, // see below
  "is_green": false // was the transaction sent by a green address?
}
}
```

and my callback.php code is this

```
require_once 'block.io/block_io.php';


$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);


$type = $data['type'];
$network = $data['data']['network'];
$address = $data['data']['address'];
$balence_change = $data['data']['balance_change'];
$tx = $data['txid'];
$confirmations = $data['confirmations'];


echo 'Type: ' . $type;
echo 'Network: ' . $network;
echo 'Address: ' . $address;
echo 'Balance change: ' . $balance_change;
echo 'Confirmations: ' . $confirmations;
```

I use testnet to send bitcoins then refresh the page but nothing is returned. The variables are all empty. Please help me to get this done.
Thanks

Comment: Are you using the paid version? Try a var_dump or print_r on $data and see what is returned. From what I remember the free version does not allow for web hook usage, and should return with an error instructing you to visit their pricing page https://block.io/pricing

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm using free version and yes the free version does not allow for webhook but I use test net just for testing then I will upgrade to paid version. When I create a notification for balance changes in this page https://block.io/docs/notifications/php it gives me "Response: 200 SUCCESS" and successfully connects to my callback.php page. When I try for non test net it gives me error that I have to upgrade for paid version. Now I will try your solution and will comment the result. thanks.

Comment: I've tested your solution: 

   ( require_once 'block.io/block_io.php';

    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

    var_dump($data); )

then I send some test net bitcoin then refreshed the callback.php page but it returned NULL . This is what block.io said about notifications: "All notification events will use JSON objects.". So is there any other way to get json data returned from api.

Comment: Oh you shouldn't be running or refreshing your callback page yourself, block.io will run it.  To s÷ if the callback is working put the json outputs into a database or create a text file with fopen fwrite

Comment: Yes you're right, I also was thinking about it. I will do it right away. Thanks.

Comment: Not again... It doesn't work. I've write the code and send bitcoins but it didn't create any file. this is the code I wrote: 

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$type = $data['type'];
$network = $data['data']['network'];
$address = $data['data']['address'];

$text = fopen("notification.txt","w");
$r = fwrite($text, $type);
$r = fwrite($text, $network);
$r = fwrite($text, $address);
fclose($text);

Comment: Hey Kyle that worked... I just didn't check the file and folder permission on my web server after that I checked them and send some bitcoin the api send me data like address and etc. Thanks Kyle. I have one more question. How can I respond to block.io with a status code between 200-299 to stop block.io from resending notifications?

Comment: As long as the file is there and runs, it will automatically respond with a status code of 200. For example if someone tries to access a page on your webserver that doesn't exist it will automatically return a status code of 404. Or if forbidden status of 500, etc.

Comment: Hi Kyle. I have another question(sorry for my endless questions). I update the database when the notification gets to callback page but block.io send three notification for each transaction which occurs. one when the transaction occurs, one when it has 1 confirmation and the last one when it gets 3 confirmations. This is like as block.io said: "confirmations": "X, X = {0,1,3} for Bitcoin, {0,1,10} for Dogecoin, {0,1,5} for Litecoin". How can I get the notification just one time e.g. when the confirmation is 1 or 3. I used If statement in my code but it doesn't work. I get all 3 notifications.

Comment: This is my code:
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true); 
$confirmations = $data['data']['confirmations']; 
if ($confirmations == 3){
    //update the database
 }

Comment: Yup just like you show above. Create a condition the checks the confirmations of a transaction and only update your database when the condition is met.

Comment: I've made it but as I said it doesn't work. I wonder what is wrong with it. It doesn't check the confirmations at first and accepts all notifications.

Comment: Actually there was a small mistake. I had to put strict comparison instead of the loosely one. if( $confirmations === 1 ){ //update database }. This worked.